# How to get the eventClick data to look the way I what it to

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the simplest data for eventClick I could find and I barely understand it.
Below is the output I have from this. I have a few questions.

1. How can I make these items show on different lines?
2. Can I add more fields because this seams to be the limet?
3. Is there any way to pass a link so I can pull in the results from database?
4. How do I use jQuery UI Dialog instead of the default popup?
5. How do change the font size and color?
   Sorry I have so many questions but after going over the docs and reading all the stackoverflow stuff about this topic I am more confused than ever.

This is what my script prints out

> Event: Richard Kurth  Thu Mar 06 2014 18:55:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific
>   Standard Time)  Thu Mar 06 2014 19:55:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard
>   Time)  7504 NE 110th St  Vancouver

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
             eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title + '  ' + calEvent.start + '  ' + calEvent.end + '  ' + calEvent.address1 + '  ' + calEvent.city);
            },

         events: "json_events.php", 


         loading: function(bool) { 
            if (bool) $('#loading').show(); 
            else $('#loading').hide(); 
         } 

      }); 

   });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `\n` to put a newline. For instance : `calEvent.title + '\n' + calEvent.start`.
2. The limit where ? In your `alert();` ? You don't have limit.
3. To get the result from your database you should see the documentation of fullCalendar. Also you have many example as [this one](http://developer-paradize.blogspot.be/2013/06/jquery-fullcalendar-integration-with.html). You should use events to specify where to search data : `events: "your_request.php"` where the php file return a Json (feed by the database).

To respect meta, some clue :

**events.php**

```
<?php
 // ... Your sql query ...

 // Your sql result to Json
 echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**fullCalendar.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // ...

   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    header: {
       //...
    },
    // Find events from database
    events: "http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/events.php",

    //...

    // Add event when clicking on a field open dialog with Jquery UI dialog
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
          buttons: {
            "Add": function() {
              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8888/fullcalendar/add_events.php', // Add request
                data: { data },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                 success: function(json) {
                   // retrieve json here
                   // see for refetchEvent() of fullCalendar (feed the calendar with new values)
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
             }
        },
      "Cancel": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
  return;
  });
 });
}
```

For the other steps you have all what you want on the documentation (fullCalendar and jQuery UI). You have everything to continue by yourself, but I stay available if you have some specific problems/questions.

Comment: I saw that you tried editing my answer. I gave you the outline. I hope it was helpful. You can edit your question if you want (with your final solution) and accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that I was answering you in the wrong place. I got it to add all the fields I wanted. Is there someplace where I can read about Changing the font size and colors

Comment: I didn't understand your outline I will need to play with and see it run before I start understanding which I could just look at code and go aha but I am still learning JavaScript and jquery

Comment: You try to learn javascript, jQuery and fullCalendar. That's a lot of things. If I remember a propertie exist for font-size and color (you should read fullCalendar documentation). I suggest you to go step by step. First step implement the calendar (without the color, dialog...)